# Can I test a program for Google Glass without Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Can I write and test a Hello World program for Google Glass without actually having it? Is there an emulator I can use to test the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a video showing that we can run it on Nexus Tablet.
Check out the link http://liliputing.com/2013/05/run-google-glass-apps-on-a-nexus-7-tablet.html

Answer (score 2):

**No...** there's not official Google Glass Emulator.

**Yes...** you can preview your cards in [playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground). This shows you how content is displayed on Google Glass.

And **yes...** you can test Google Glass apps on Android Device (Nexus 7, Nexus 5, ...) with [this](https://github.com/zhuowei/Xenologer). If you don't know how to do that, look at [this](http://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/). But don't expect, that it'll work without bugs.