# Google Glass - development

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm roaming around the internet, but not find any exact solution.

I creted - 
Client ID
Wallent Account
Downloaded GDK

but while starting development, it is saying required google glass.

Q. without real google glass how i can start development ?

Comment: How can you develop when you can't even test it on the real gadget?

Comment: Hi Johny, thats why looking for emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no official Glass Emulator released.

To solve this you need to do some hack by installing Glass APKs into Nexus 7 tablet and you can operate  it via http://google.com/myglass

For more info: [elekslabs](http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html)

Note: Some of the feature doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There is no official google glass emulator.I am also developing Glass app without Glass.Its like building a bridge in air.Dont know whether its fine or fails.Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465622/can-i-test-a-program-for-google-glass-without-google-glass).Also to convert your phone into glass.Please check this [link](http://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/).Also there is another [blog](http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html) how to setup glass on phone.I think someone already solved your problem on stackoverflow.Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator) also. :)

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible (legal) to create a AVD for google glass.