# Running Google Glass sample app on Android Virtual Device(emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-glass

I am trying to run the Timer sample google glass app, but when I run the project, it gets installed and then says DONE, however, I don't see anything on the emulator. I know there is no Launcher and so I tried the RUN CONFIGURATION but I don't see any activity in the dropdown when I chose the Launch option. Any thoughts or guides on to do this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone successfully using an existing AVD to run GDK apps. I think the idea is that an emulator will ship with the first official release of the GDK.

Comment: There is no avd for Glass.You should have glass to test.or other wise to test some functionality.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465622/can-i-test-a-program-for-google-glass-without-google-glass

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no avd/emulator available for Glass.But if still you are interested converting your mobile phone into glass.Check these link i.e [1](http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html),[2](http://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator).But no one works completely treating your phone as Glass.
As you have mentioned above that you try to install an app on emulator.The main reason why it is not showing up is that:

Move to AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

This is the normal code for the main launcher activity of android.This is the main activity which is launched in the emulator/avd

```
         <intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>
```

While in Glass code you find something like this.There is no launcher in Glass but still you can add.Here you only found out the voice trigger which open your app

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/voicetrigger" />
    </activity>
```